# asp mvc 6 include ckeditor via bower

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gulp, ckeditor, asp.net-core-mvc, bower

I've included CKEditor (4.5.3) via bower.js, but on the View, I just can't figure out how to make it work.

I'm working on a default MVC6 project template and I haven't changed any gulp.js paths.

I'm guessing I'm missing something there, since It wants to join scripts from `paths.webroot + "js/**/*.js";`
and the CKEditor is located inside `wwwroot/lib/ckeditor`

Everything works fine if I add `<script src="/lib/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>` on the View...

But that's missing the point, since gulp should take care of it.

Can anyone please help?